# Node Express return 404 custom message

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using NodeJS with Express and when an Endpoint is not found Express returns [image]

I'd like to return a Custom 404 Message instead of the above image whenever an Endpoint is miss-typed.

I've tried adding the following to `app.js`

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.status(404).send("Sorry can't find that!")
})
```

But this just returns **ALL** endpoints with

> Sorry can't find that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make that this the **last** 'route' in app.js

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.status(404).send("Sorry can't find that!")
})
```

The order your specify your routes is important.